# Cannot convert HttpPostedFileBase to Byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that takes in a HttpPostedFileBase (a .jpg or .png, etc.).

```
public ActionResult SaveImage(HttpPostedFileBase ImageData)
{
  //code
}
```

`ImageData` becomes a `System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper` object with these properties:

```
ContentLength: 71945
ContentType: "image/png"
FileName: "foo.png"
InputStream: {System.Web.HttpInputStream}
```

I don't have any problems taking the ImageData and converting it to an Image, and then converting the Image to a byte[] and then to a base64 string - but I tried converting it directly into a byte[] with the following code:

```
byte[] imgData;

using (Stream inputStream = ImageData.InputStream)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
    if (memoryStream == null)
    {
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    }

    imgData = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

`memoryStream` is always empty by the time `imgData = memoryStream.ToArray();` is invoked, so `imgData` ends up being null as well.

I'm having a hard time understanding why I cannot read this InputStream into a MemoryStream. The InputStream seems seems fine, with the exception of the readTimeout and writeTimeout properties throwing `timeouts are not supported on this stream`.  What am I doing wrong, and how come I can't convert ImageData into a byte[]?

Just in case, this is my AJAX call. Could it be an issue with the `contentType` or `processData` options being set to false?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'SaveImage',
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#loadingScreenModal").modal('toggle');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // etc.
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** I resolved the issue by converting the `HttpPostedFileBase` to an `Image`, and then converting the `Image` to a `byte[]`, but I'm still interested in figuring out why I have to perform this intermediate step.

```
Image i = Image.FromStream(ImageData.InputStream, true, true);
byte[] imgData = imageToByteArray(thumb);

public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

**UPDATE #2:** I think it probably stands to reason that the problem with my code is the code within the `if (memoryStream == null)` block never being invoked.

Comment: `memoryStream` will never be null at that line.

Comment: Read here how to read the stream: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JoeEnos I updated my question to reflect that it's empty, not null.

Comment: Your code is working for me as-is. If you can include the relevant parts of your HTML for the form, and anything that you may have left out of the SaveImage method, that would be helpful.

Comment: @JoeEnos I posted the AJAX call and some additional information about what I'm doing.

Comment: @JoeEnos I think your first comment solves the problem, if you'd like to post it as an answer. I think that the issue I was having was sort of a simple typographical error.

Comment: what is THUMB variable ?

Comment: @Muflix An Image object - take a look at the imageToByteArray function's argument.

Comment: so i guess it should be "i" variable then ?

Comment: Does this need an Update #3 showing the final version of the corrected code (corresponding to the  selected answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ended up being the `memoryStream == null` check, as JoeEnos suggested.  `MemoryStream` is instantiated on the line directly above this check - so it should never be null - and should be checked with `if (memoryStream.Length == 0)` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `BinaryReader` class to read a string into a byte array:

```
byte[] imgData;

using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ImageData.InputStream))
{
    imgData = reader.ReadBytes(ImageData.ContentLength);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this doesn't work for me.  The code I posted should, as far as I know, convert an HttpPostedFileBase into a MemoryStream, but it doesn't.  There's obviously a gap in my understanding that I am interested in trying to figure out.

Comment: You can't "convert" from one type of stream to another - you have to read from one and write to the other (which is what `CopyTo` does.  Do you _really_ need a `MemoryStream` or was that just a way to get to the underlying bytes?  Why doesn't the answer work for you?

Comment: I don't know why the answer doesn't work for me because I don't fully understand the way MemoryStreams work.  I'm solely interested in the underlying bytes; I want to save the image to a database as `varbinary(max)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar code, wherein I read the stream directly into a byte[] like so:

```
var streamLength = ImageData.InputStream.Length;
var imageBytes = new byte[streamLength];
ImageData.InputStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

I then store imageBytes into the database as a `varbinary(MAX)`. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Model Code

```
public class AdminDetailsModel
{
    public byte[] AdminImage { get; set; }
 }
```

View Code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AdminDetails", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{   
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminImage, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" />                              
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code like this in Your Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(AdminDetailsModel viewmodel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData"];
    viewmodel.Image = ConvertToByte(file);
    db.YourDbContextSet.Add(viewmodel);
    db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public byte[] ConvertToByte(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        byte[] imageByte = null;
        BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
        imageByte = rdr.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);
        return imageByte;
    }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you Prakash, but this doesn't really address my problem. I'm not so much concerned about the *View*, and the ViewModel you give in your example assumes that the `HttpPostedFileBase` is already a byte[].  I'm trying to figure out why I have to take the intermediate step and convert the `HttpPostedFileBase` to an `Image` before I convert it into a `byte[]`.